# "Will-change memory consumption is too high" firefox issue?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

First of all what does this warning means?

> Will-change memory consumption is too high. Budget limit is the
> document surface area multiplied by 3 (35516 px). Occurrences of
> will-change over the budget will be ignored.

Secondly how do I resolve this.

I'm facing this warning in both firefox and the google chrome browser.

Comment: Sounds like you're over powering/filling the C/GPU memory with `will-change` instructions. Without knowing to what and when this is applied it will be hard to assist.

Comment: The error simply means that there are too many `will-change` properties. Read [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change), especially the warnings. Now are you using frameworks or libraries that may use `will-change`? Please mention those in your edit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I got the same problem and it could be resolved as followings:

First of all, please find the term "**will-change**" in your CSS files or snippets. For example, it looks like this.

```css
.sidebar {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

You can replace "**transform**" with either "**auto**" or "**transform !important**". They both resolved my problem!

A brief explanation from ***mozilla***:

> The above example adds the will-change property directly to the
>   stylesheet, which will cause the browser to keep the optimization in
>   memory for much longer than it is needed. [will-change MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change)

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I'll do try to run it, if that resolves my problem, i will let you know.